# How do website create a Horizontal Bar at Bottom of Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have visited some sites where when I scroll half a page, a semi-transparent horizontal column of 100-150px height appears right at the bottom of the page with an image on the left and some message, links on the right.

How can I create it?

Comment: Can you give an example? Sounds like just a DIV, with appropriate styling, but hard to say without seeing one.

Comment: one like https://www.rapidshare.com/ ? I want to know too

Comment: rapidshare always shows it, so that's not what I am looking for. I remember seeing it on techcrunch, but it's not there anymore. Yes I think they use a div. I am wondering how do they make it appear when user scrolls half the page and how do they display an image to the left and text to the right in that semi-transparent div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just a css rule.

```
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Chrome, click CTRL-SHIFT I, then click on the magnifying glass in the bottom left-hand corner to inspect the element. That's the best way to see how they did it on the site you're looking at.

In IE, F12 gives you the Developer Tools, where the arrow selector tool does the same job. In Firefox, use Firebug.

Then just copy their HTML. And Javascript too if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use an element with a style similar to following:

```
#footer {
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #330000;
}
```

and then lay things inside it as you wish.

Comment: thanks but this is visible all the time. How to make it visible when user scrolls half the page?

Comment: JavaScript. Catch the `scroll` event, check the `scrollOffset` property against `scrollHeight`, and show or hide the footer as needed.

Comment: Russ, just detect the user screen height, and then follow his scroll. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592420/use-jquery-to-show-a-div-only-when-scroll-position-is-between-2-points

Comment: Guh. Sorry, indeed, it's `scrollTop`, not `scrollOffset`.

Comment: Spot on Frankie! Can you post it as an answer so that I can mark it!