# Fixed in window "Back To Top" button, which is visible when a HTML Page has scrolled 200 Pixels, for example

Tags: html, css, scroll, visible

i'm working on a website and wondering if there is any code that I can add to a "Fixed in Window" Item that will be visible once a visitor has scrolled 200 Pixels, for example.

Couldn't find anything specifically for this in any other questions.

Cheers

My bad, I found this, perhaps this is what I'm looking for [Use jQuery to show a div only when scroll position is between 2 points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592420/use-jquery-to-show-a-div-only-when-scroll-position-is-between-2-points). Correct me if I'm wrong :-)

Comment: You mean to say you didn't find your exact solution to your problem. You have to at least try out something and post what you've tried. You expect someone to do that for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can detect scrolling position with use of j Query and then if scroll is moved hide your div. Below given is example code. please review it and work on it little bit according to your requirement it is working fine with me.

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
            <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
            $(window).load(function(){
            $(function() {
                $.fn.scrollBottom = function() {
                    return $(document).height() - this.scrollTop() - this.height();
                };

                var $el = $('#sidebar>div');
                var $window = $(window);
                var top = $el.parent().position().top;

                $window.bind("scroll resize", function() {
                    var gap = $window.height() - $el.height() - 10;
                    var visibleFoot = 172 - $window.scrollBottom();
                    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop()

                    if (scrollTop < top + 10) {
                        $el.css({
                            top: (top - scrollTop) + "px",
                            bottom: "auto"
                        });
                    } else if (visibleFoot > gap) {
                        $el.css({
                            top: "auto",
                            bottom: visibleFoot + "px"
                        });
                    } else {
                        $el.css({


                            //use your css property here if you want to display none a div
                            display: none,
                            bottom: "auto"



                        });
                    }
                }).scroll();
            });
            });//]]>  

            </script>
```