# Change a element's CSS when browser scrolls to it

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change an element's CSS as soon as the browser scrolls to it or when the browser touch it.

Here's an image that'll help explain it better:

[Image http://i282.photobucket.com/albums/kk246/leeV18/publicweb/jquery-help-1_zpscba356f6.png](http://i282.photobucket.com/albums/kk246/leeV18/publicweb/jquery-help-1_zpscba356f6.png)
Like in the example image, I want to change the background of the div as soon as the web browser scrolls to it or touch it.

I think you can do this with jquery, but I'm a total newbie at it. Please help if anyone can, thank you.

Comment: You have to check the document's `scrollHeight` and compare that to where your `div` is. You can do that with jQuery, have a look at that.

Comment: A good answer to this is posted here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592420/use-jquery-to-show-a-div-only-when-scroll-position-is-between-2-points

Comment: What's the point? If you can't see it, why not have that CSS from the beginning - they'll still only see it once they've scrolled it into view

Comment: Some div in my website were slowing down my pages, I want to hide them until visitors scrolls to it.

Comment: And there's no other way to improve performance?

Comment: What are you doing in CSS that's slowing down performance?

Answer (score 4):

here is you solution

http://jsfiddle.net/hushme/VF46X/

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

        $('.hide').each(function(){
    var h = $(window).scrollTop();

        var o = $(this).offset().top;
            var height = $(this).outerHeight();
             var t = o-(height*1.3);
            if (h >= t) {
                $(this) .css('background','green')

            }else {$(this) .css('background','blue')}
        });
    });
```

Comment: code works great. What if I want the div to immediately change when the web browser touches the edge of it, instead of not like 20px after.

Comment: change to what will please explain

Comment: That should just be `var t = o - height;`. However, don't forget to add the behavior for when it comes back down from the top!

Comment: change "var t = o-(height*1.3);" to "var t = o - height;" ?